# segment sentences with spaCy tokenizer exceptions changed in v2?

Tags: python, tokenize, spacy

After reading [this](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/592) which works with Python 3.5, spaCy version 1.1.2. I tried doing this

```
from spacy.lang.en import English
nlp = spacy.load('en')
text2 = u'he has a ph.D. in tacology'
nlp.Defaults.tokenizer_exceptions['Ph.D.'] = [{'F':'Ph.D.'}]
tokens = parser(text2)
tokens = [token.orth_ for token in tokens if not token.orth_.isspace()]
```

This gives:

[u'he', u'has', u'a', u'ph', u'.', u'D.', u'in', u'tacology']

when I was expecting:

[u'he', u'has', u'a', u'ph.D.', u'in', u'tacology']

Why does tokenizer_exceptions not work? Is it because I'm using version 2 and it is implemented differently?

How would I do the equivalent in v2?

NB I did look at Tokenizer.add_special-case in the [v2 spacy docs here](http://here) but I couldn't figure out a solution

Answer (score 0):

Not sure as to your core spaCy question, but you could check for 'Ph', '.' and 'D.', then check if they're in sequence and replace them with 'Ph.D’ as a workaround.

Comment: Thx: core question = can you still do nlp.Defaults.tokenizer_exceptions['Ph.D.'] = [{'F':'Ph.D.'}] in version 2